# Replace double by single quotes on `find` files content

Tags: sed, find

I try to ESLint my javascript code. An annoying requirement is to have all strings with single quotes: some of mine are double quoted. I want to replace them by single quoted. I can list all files from `src` folder.

1: `find . | grep -v ".git" | grep -v "node_modules" | grep -v "scripts" | grep src`

I read on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001148/how-to-replace-single-quotes-to-double-quotes-in-bash) that we can do it likeso:

2: `echo "\"Hello\"" | sed "s/"/\'/g"`. But, you know, I am afraid my computer explode and shit.

I call 1: as `Fernando` and 2: as `Eduardo`. Except for the `echo "\"Hello\""` part, we can run `Fernando | xargs cat | Eduardo`.

Will it work? Is there some cleverererer way to do it? Who knows... yes, if you know, let me know as well. :-P

Comment: Edit the question and provide a sample and the expected output.

Comment: Dude: `eslint src/ --fix`

Comment: @spinks I have hope this could be a thing, maybe THE thing. However, this wild error log appears when I run the command: `Error: Cannot find module 'optionator'`

Comment: Your find-command is most probably not doing what you want. i.e. `grep -v ".git"` will not only remove all files with extension "git" but also (because "." is a regular expression) a file like "xgitter.src", which you probably would want to keep. Describe which files you want to include or exclude in your result set.